# The window opened from windows.create isn't scrollable in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome-extension, scrollbar, firefox-addon-webextensions

I created in my chrome extension (which because it's a webextension it works in Firefox) a window with
`chrome.windows.create(windowobj);`
where `windowobj` is an object with fields like the url, width, height, type='popup' and state='normal'.

When I use it in chrome I can use the new popup window normally, scrolling through the page. However, when I use it in Firefox I can't scroll in the new window. I tried resizing it, still doesn't scroll.  When I change state to 'fullscreen' it still doesn't let me scroll.

(I'm using Firefox 59.0, if that makes any difference)

Thanks for your help,
MagnetPlant

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Firefox. Try circumventing it by playing with CSS properties like `overflow` and such.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug for this on Bugzilla - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1331906 - which is still not fixed and the solution found by Techniko was this:

> fix.html: (you could easily shorten this if you wanted to)
>
> `<script>
>    var url = new URL(window.location.href);
>    var parsedUrl = url.searchParams.get('url');
>    location.href = parsedUrl;
>    </script>`
>
> And then I set the url for a popup window to
>
> `windowobj.url = chrome.runtime.getURL('fix.html') + '?url=' + url;`
>
> For some reason after redirecting the url through there, the scrolling
>   in the popup window works normally